# How to add copyright to published EXE (.Net Core)

Tags: .net-core

How can I add copyright/company information to the EXE generated when publishing a .Net Core app?

Actually, by adding those information in the .csproj, the generated DLL is updated, but not the EXE.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the project in solution select "Properties" Under Package Tab. 
Change Company & Copyright.
You got to use "dotnet build -r win10-x64" to produce .exe

Comment: dotnet build -r win10-x64 does not make the .exe, only the .dll


I have to use dotnet publish to get the .exe