# .NET Core publish as exe: How to put assembly infos into exe

Tags: c#, .net-core, assemblyinfo, .net-core-2.1

My question is similar to this one ([How to add copyright to published EXE (.Net Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109630/how-to-add-copyright-to-published-exe-net-core)) which wasn't really answered.

I have a .NET core executable project.

I can put assembly information like `AssemblyFileVersion` into my .NET Core project and compile it, it will produce a DLL and Windows Explorer will show this info in the details tab of the file properties.

When I publish as native x64 EXE, I'll get an EXE of the same name and the original DLL.

But only the DLL will contain the assembly info and the EXE will be basically blank (and will have a really old last changed date to boot).

It tried to clean my workspace (killing .vs, bin, obj, packages), nothing helps.

Is there a way?

Comment: What .NET Core version are you using and what build, publish arguments did you use? That `exe` file is just a stub that executes the actual binary code in the DLL. Before .NET Core 3.0, you wouldn't even get that `exe` unless you published a self-contained package that included the runtime

Comment: In fact, before 3.0 the only executable targets were console and web apps, where assemblyinfo isn't really a priority.

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 with self-contained x64 exe