# dotnet publish does not respect/inherit assembly info for the published exe. How do I set Product Name on the exe that's created via publish?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to be able to set Product Name in the exe file that is generated from dotnet publish inside a CI pipeline

Currently building in Azure Pipelines and using the Assembly Info (.Net Core & .Net Standard) task to populate these fields.

The project DLL has all the metadata as expected. The compiled exe does not. Is there a way to get the exe to inherit all the assembly info set in the project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that this has been fixed with Visual Studio 2019.

btw same questions as this here: [.NET Core publish as exe: How to put assembly infos into exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236610/net-core-publish-as-exe-how-to-put-assembly-infos-into-exe)